# Javascript Object Finding Game

Tags: javascript, html

im currently having a big problem with a javascript little game im programming. Essentially the player finds specific objects, but to make it easier i want to make a menu to show which objects are there to find

```
for (let i = 0; i < figuresCount; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "figure" + randomNumber(1,10)+ ".svg";
        img.id = "figure"+i;
        var div = document.getElementById("main");
        div.appendChild(img);
        document.getElementById("figure"+i).style.top = randomNumber(10, 95) + "%";
        document.getElementById("figure"+i).style.left = randomNumber(1, 90) + "%";
        document.getElementById("figure"+i).style.width = randomNumber(30, 60) + "px";
        document.getElementById("figure"+i).style.transform = "rotate("+ randomNumber(0,360) +"deg)";
        document.getElementById("figure"+i).style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("figure"+i).addEventListener("click", findFigure);
    }
```

this is the loop where the objects are taken and shown on the playing field. The problem im having is saving the same randomized photos in the menu. Another thing that is difficult is that when a specific object is found, then the object in the menu should disappear too. Can someone help me with this?

I tried creating another variable and saving it there but it does not work.

```
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");
        menu.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: So what's the main issue you have now?

Comment: the randomized images that are saved in the playing field. i want them to be also saved in a small div so it shows the player which figure to find (so like a hint)

Comment: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010 Can you replicate your issue here?